# Prove the inverse of an integer matrix has only integer entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that if $A$ is a square matrix with integer entries and $\det(A)=\pm 1$, then the inverse of $A$ contains all integer entries.

Comment: What do you know? What have you tried?

Comment: We find this statement everywhere on the web, but it's only for n > 1. For 1x1 matrices [a], the inverse is [1/a] and does not have an integer element, except if a = 1

Comment: @jherek: No, it also has integer coefficients if $a=-1$. The $1\times 1$ integer matrix $[a]$ has a "matrix" $1\times 1$ inverse if and only if $a=1$ or $a=-1$. When $a=-1$, the inverse is $[-1]$.

Comment: (above, "has 'matrix' $1\times 1$ inverse' should be understood to mean 'integer matrix inverse')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the inverse written in terms of the adjugate matrix.

Comment: This is one part of the statement that- "The inverse of an integer matrix $M$ is again an integer matrix if and only if the determinant of $M$ is exactly $\pm 1$. Now my question is how to show if $M^{-1}$ has integer entries then $\det(M)=\pm 1$

Comment: @KushalBhuyan A general statement is that a matrix over $R$ is invertible (over $R$) if and only if $\det M$ is a unit of $R$. The only units of $R=\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm1$, so this proves the statement you're looking for. More explicitly, we know that $\det M \cdot \det M^{-1} = 1$. Since $\det M$ and $\det M^{-1}$ are both integers (since $M$ and $M^{-1}$ are integer valued matrices), the only way for this to happen is if $\det M = \det M^{-1} = \pm 1$.